# ClickOnce installation error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I had correct ClickOnce installer for application which was created in Visual Studio 2008 (C#, .NET 3.5). After this project conversion for Visual Studio 2013 I can't to create correct ClickOnce installer. Getting this error on ClickOnce application launches.

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
        Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
        Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
        System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
        clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
        dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
        dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

    SOURCES
    file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/<username>/Start%20Menu/Programs/<programname>/<programname>.appref-ms%7C


        Deployment url          : file://MyServer/d/My_Setup/MyApp.application
        Deployment Provider url     : file://MyServer/d/My_Setup/MyApp.application
        Application url         : ile://MyServer/d/My_Setup/Application%20Files/MyApp_1_0_0_711/MyApp.exe.manifest

    IDENTITIES
        Deployment Identity     : MyApp.application, Version=1.0.0.711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cdfbb15e6196321d, processorArchitecture=msil
        Application Identity        : MyApp.exe, Version=1.0.0.711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cdfbb15e6196321d, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

    APPLICATION SUMMARY
        * Installable application.

    ERROR SUMMARY
        Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
        * Activation of \\MyServer\d\My_Setup\MyApp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
            + Value does not fall within the expected range.

    COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
        No transaction error was detected.

    WARNINGS
        There were no warnings during this operation.

    OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:15] : Activation of \\MyServer\d\My_Setup\MyApp.application has started.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:15] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:15] : Installation of the application has started.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:16] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Found compatible runtime version 2.0.50727.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil using Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil using WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Detecting dependent assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304, processorArchitecture=msil using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=msil.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:19] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:47] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:47] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:53] : Installation of application has successfully completed.

    ERROR DETAILS
        Following errors were detected during this operation.
        * [01/07/2015 11:34:53] System.ArgumentException
            - Value does not fall within the expected range.
            - Source: System.Deployment
            - Stack trace:
                at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
                at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

    COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
        * Transaction at [01/07/2015 11:34:53]
            + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
                - Status: Installed
                - HRESULT: 0x0
                - Manifest: DHMC5ZJ6.ABJ.application
            + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
                - Status: Set
                - HRESULT: 0x0
            + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
                - Status: Installed
                - HRESULT: 0x0
                - Manifest: MyApp.exe.manifest
            + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
                - Status: Installed
                - HRESULT: 0x0
                - File: Purchase\Reports\rpt_PurchaseOrderFooterLat.rpt
            + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
                - Status: Installed
                - HRESULT: 0x0
                - File: Resourses\Printer.png
            + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
                - Status: Installed
                - HRESULT: 0x0
                - File: Resourses\stock_mail-receive1.png 

.............
```

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, this has little to do with your actual manifest. It means that the ClickOnce cache directory is corrupted somehow.

Try to remove the following folders (note: make sure there is nothing in there belonging to other applications!):

- inside `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Apps\2.0` any folder except `Data` (the application cache)
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\assembly` (the download cache)

Then try to install / update the application. It will work normally.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Also I tried to install  on other computer where the program wasn't installed. Nothing works.

Comment: Old app with out of date manifest. 2.0 VS2005 -> 4.0 vs2013
Using the articles from Robin 
"https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/how-to-move-a-clickonce-deployment/" 
and 
"https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-extend-an-existing-certificate-even-if-it-has-expired/" 
I was able to migrate the app and update the manifest. 
I have used this in the past without issue. 
This time I had a single user that had the error as above " Application.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:  The deployment identity does not match the subscription."

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file with .bat extension.
Copy this in the file.

`rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache`

Run the file.